# Can you link values for two JFormattedTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, documentlistener

I've got an interface with 2 JFormattedTextFields for which I need the values (not just the displayed text) to be identical.  Ideally they should both be editable, with a change in one being mirrored in the other.

I started by just sharing a single Document between the two, but quickly ran into the problem that this only links the displayed text, not the underlying value.  (Silly me!)
I haven't tried adding reciprocal PropertyChangeListeners for the "value" property because I would expect that to set up an infinite loop of modification.

Am I missing something?  Is there some way to do this?  Or am I stuck with only allowing users to edit one of the two and only having the value propagate in one direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> I need the values (not just the displayed text) to be identical.
>   Ideally they should both be editable, with a change in one being
>   mirrored in the other.

- use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html),
- for example (only the one directions)

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TextLabelMirror {

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20);

    public TextLabelMirror() {
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            private void updateLabel(DocumentEvent e) {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        field1.setText(field.getText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 0));
        mainPanel.add(field);
        mainPanel.add(field1);
    }

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextLabelMirror");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextLabelMirror().getComponent());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think DocumentListener would work for me, since I'm using JFormattedTextField objects, and what I want to have copied is not just the displayed text (I can do that just by having both use the same Document) but the value itself, once it's been validated.  Also, I guess I assumed that calling setText() would trigger a DocumentEvent, so I couldn't use this in both directions.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: use only `setText()` instead of manipulating with `Document`, `DocumentListene`r isn't designated to firing events to `Document`, then have to use `AbstractDocument` or `DocumentFilter` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use a key listener.  You simply add a key listener to both fields using the below code.  the reason you need the other events is it will throw errors unless you have them in the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;   
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CreateGrid 
{    
    JFrame thisframe;
    JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1, jFormattedTextField2;

    public CreateGrid()
    {
        GridLayout thislayout = new GridLayout(0,2);
        thisframe = new JFrame();
        thisframe.setLayout(thislayout);

        jFormattedTextField1 = new JFormattedTextField();
        jFormattedTextField2 = new JFormattedTextField();
        jFormattedTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
            {                
                JFormattedTextField textField = (JFormattedTextField) e.getSource();
                String text = textField.getText();
                jFormattedTextField2.setText(text);
            }
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
            {
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
            }            
        });
        jFormattedTextField2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
            {                
                JFormattedTextField textField = (JFormattedTextField) e.getSource();
                String text = textField.getText();
                jFormattedTextField1.setText(text);
            }
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
            {
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
           }            
       });
       thisframe.add(jFormattedTextField1);
       thisframe.add(jFormattedTextField2);
       thisframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       thisframe.setVisible(true);
       thisframe.pack();
   }

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new CreateGrid();
}
```

}
I have tested this out and it works perfectly what ever you type into one field will show up in the other as you type it.