# Is it possible to connect two JTextFields to edit both at once in real time

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

The problem is:

I have 2 JTextFields, 1 is input field and 2 is output. What I want to do is when type somethink to 1 field, that text will be coppied and modified to field 2. The problem is I would preffer to make changes in second field, while editting. I can do it after button click or accept of change but I want to do it in real time. I can guess I should use somekind of property listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield) you can do it with `documentlistener`

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    //do something
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    //do something
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
   //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14980155/714968)